# Muilti deploy DLLs from external Projects into single WSP

Tags: deployment, solution-package, solution-deployment, gac

I'm trying to build a single .WSP that should contains multiple DLLs from External projects. 
I've been following that this tutorial: [Link](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/)

I've followed all steps but on deploy , DLLS doesn't appear into GAC.

Comment: Did you select Add existing Assembly and select the dll?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 0):

The article you used, specifies that you have to add the dlls into the package -> advanced tab. I assume you have done this and then published & installed the WSP or deployed the project via VS.

Note that SharePoint 2010 is based on .NET version 3.5 and GAC is c:\windows\assembly

However, SharePoint 2013 is based on .NET framework 4.5. The directory for the GAC in .NET 4.0 and up are located in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly. Start in the GAC_MSIL directory, if dll does'nt contain any unmanaged code. It is a bit hard to reach to your dll file as you have to search it in the folders.

Hence, the simple answer may be that the dlls are deployed into the GAC but you are not looking in the right location.